# Column carousel slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I've created a three column slider which seems to work fine in programmes like **Brackets**.

When I try to use the `slider` in wordpress, It doesn't seem to function. Have I done something wrong in the code for it to not function on my website?

This is the page that I have tried to include it on: [click here](http://wrighthand.uk.w3pcloud.com/resources/)

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                    interval: 0
                })
                $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
                    var next = $(this).next();
                    if (!next.length) {
                        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
                    }
                    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                    if (next.next().length > 0) {
                        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                    } else {
                        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                    }
                });
            });
```

```css
       .container-fluid {
        width: 50%;
        padding-top: 20px;
       } 
       .carousel {
        overflow: hidden;
       }
       .carousel-inner {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0%;
       }
       .carousel-inner>.item.next, .carousel-inner>.item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
       }
       .carousel-inner>.item.prev, .carousel-inner>.item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
       }
       .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
        background: transparent!important;
        width: 25%;
       }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
 
  <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>
  <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
       <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.mad.uk.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/chriss.jpg"></a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.mad.uk.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/chrism.jpg"></a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
       <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.mad.uk.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/stu.jpg"></a>
       </div>
      </div>
            <div class="item">
       <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.mad.uk.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/gill.jpg"></a>
       </div>
      </div>
             <div class="item">
       <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.mad.uk.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/georgie.jpg"></a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div><a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/x6xQ8Qp.png"/></a> <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6eZV5a.png"/></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I have also ran the code on a pen which is included [here](https://codepen.io/kellett/pen/vRZVEB) and it seems to be working fine, my guess is that it could be something to do with the way I've implemented in onto the site; I'm not too certain.

Answer (score 0):

did u make this on the page itself? if so u have to copy all this code and paste on a codeblock.
check the console for more details and share it

Comment: are u loading jqurey 2 times? in the wordress and the codeblock?

Comment: By "codeblox" are you refering to the code module inside of a wordpress page? If so, I've only reference jquery in the code module on the wordpress page like in the above code.

Comment: I'll do a screen recording, it'll make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

this is the way, it work on my worppress default theme

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- IF YOUR THEME AND WORDPRESS ALL READY HAVE JSQUERY AND BOOTSTARP DONT ADD THIS IMPORTEM FROMM YOUR ASSESTS-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- IF YOUR THEME AND WORDPRESS ALL READY HAVE JSQUERY AND BOOTSTARP DONT ADD THIS IMPORTEM FROMM YOUR ASSESTS-->

    <style type="text/css">
         .container-fluid {
        width: 50%;
        padding-top: 20px;
       } 
       .carousel {
        overflow: hidden;
       }
       .carousel-inner {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0%;
       }
       .carousel-inner>.item.next, .carousel-inner>.item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
       }
       .carousel-inner>.item.prev, .carousel-inner>.item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
       }
       .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
        background: transparent!important;
        width: 25%;
       }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            div class="col-md-12 center-block">
                <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.mad.uk.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/chriss.jpg"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.mad.uk.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/chrism.jpg"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.mad.uk.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/stu.jpg"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <div class="item">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.mad.uk.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/gill.jpg"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
             <div class="item">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.mad.uk.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/georgie.jpg"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/x6xQ8Qp.png"/></a> <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6eZV5a.png"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <
<script type="text/javascript">

                $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                    interval: 0
                })
                $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
                    var next = $(this).next();
                    if (!next.length) {
                        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
                    }
                    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                    if (next.next().length > 0) {
                        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                    } else {
                        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                    }
                });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm still doesn't seem to work for me, so I'm guessing it's the theme? I did a screen record of what's happening. If I remove one of the divs in the inspect it works, but when I then try to do it in the code, its doesnt. https://youtu.be/euNrTFpf2Iw

Comment: yea i made a mistake on the divs tag check all of them for sure but one is not closed

Comment: Still no luck even after adding the ammends, must be the theme